# A pattern to match [characters]:[characters] inside an URL

Tags: regex

I have an url like below and wanted to use RegEx to extract segments like: `Id:Reference`, `Title:dfgdfg`, `Status.Title:Current Status`, `CreationDate:Logged`...

This is the closest pattern I got `[=,][^,]*:[^,]*[,&]` but obviously the result is not as expected, any better ideas?

P.S. I'm using `[^,]` to matach any characters except `,` because `,` will not exist the segment.

This is the site using for regex pattern matching.
http://regexpal.com/

The URL:
`http://localhost/site/=powerManagement.power&query=_Allpowers&attributes=Id:Reference,Title:dfgdfg,Status.Title:Current Status,CreationDate:Logged,RaiseUser.Title:标题,_MinutesToBreach&sort_by=CreationDate"`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified what programming language you use. But almost all with support this:

```
([\p{L}\.]+):([\p{L}\.]+)
```

`\p{L}` matches a Unicode character in any language, provided that your regex engine support Unicode. [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/yS2kW1/1).

You can extract the matches via capturing groups if you want.

Comment: You nailed it. But you may want to include character classes just incase supported by the language that OP is using such as `([[:alpha:]\.]+):([[:alpha:]\.]+)`.

Comment: @alvits thanks for the suggestion. `[:alpha:]` doesn't capture the Chinese (??) characters that the OP was using so I used `\p{L}` for Unicode.

Comment: Your answer was updated while I was about to ask about the Unicode part. It works, Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In python:

```
import re
matchobj = re.match("^.*Id:(.*?),Title:(.*?),.*$", url, )
Id = matchobj.group(1)
Title = matchobj.group(2)
```